# JavaScript array length is incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of data called 'plotData' which consists of any number of 'rows' of data, which are just 4-element arrays.  The array 'plotData' is appended to using a $.post() script a few lines down on in the code.  The '...' is where some of the variables shown in the post request are loaded.

```
console.log("plotData (before update): ", plotData);
console.log("plotData length: ", plotData.length);

...
...
...

$.post(
    "/csvgen",
    {node_num: nodes.toString(), start_time: startTime.toString(), end_time: endTime.toString()},
    function(data){
        var nodeData = $.csv.toArrays(data);

        nodeData.forEach(function(element){
            plotData.push(element);
        });
    },
    "text"
);
```

I am logging the array and the array.length in the console, believing that these two method calls should execute sequentially.  When I look at the console output, the console log of the array shows that there are 28 entries, but the console log of the plotData.length is 14.  As the array is appended, it turns out that the actual length of the plotData is always 14 greater than the plotData.length console output.

The 'plotData' array is read outside of this code, but not modified.

What is the reason for this?

**Edit to add log**

```
Can't plot empty data set
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
plotData (before update):  []
plotData length:  0
plotData (before update):  [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
plotData length:  14
plotData (before update):  [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
plotData length:  28
plotData (before update):  [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
plotData length:  50
```

The first error is b/c the dataset is empty when I instantiate my plot.

Comment: Could you include copy of of a console log ?

Comment: I believe that this is an issue with inspector tools. In order to save memory, the console will not display or compute all the properties of the object until you expand it. Since you explicitly told it to log out the length, it does that but nothing else. So when the $.post is finally resolved, and you expand it, the same object will be updated in the console, giving you the new total

Comment: Ok, so after playing around for a while, I believe that alexdmejias is correct.  This is a problem with my debugger.  When I expand the 'logged' array in the debugger, it always expands to the current value of the array and doesn't appear to create a static log as I had assumed.  As a result, I was seeing 'old' data in the length and 'new' data in the array b/c the post request completed with the updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the debugger (Chrome) that I am using, not in the code itself.  The code is behaving as expected.

The "console.log()" function does log single values, but when an array is logged, there are no values logged.  The debugger just makes a note to itself to say "hey, that array was logged right there".  So when the user opens the array from within the log, the log dynamically generates the array based on the contents at the time that the log is opened.

So, to connect this information with the symptoms, the actual length of the array was being logged appropriately, but a pointer to the array was logged.  By the time the user got around to hitting the breakpoint, the post request shown had returned, adding data to the 'plotData' array.  This made it appear - upon halt - that the plotData.length and the actual length were different.

The credit for this answer should go to alexdmejias (see comments to the question).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code logs *before* it calls `post()`. Try adding logging statements to the end of your callback function -- they should show the "correct" value (after the new rows are appended).

Comment: I want to read the last data in 'plotData' in order to construct the post request, so I need to know the length of 'plotData' first.

Comment: OK, but that does not seem relevant to your question or my answer. The reason your array is generally larger than logged is because you log BEFORE you make a request for more data (which would ultimately result in an enlargement of your array). If you add logging to the end of your callback function, you will be able to see the larger array size.

Comment: The order was related, but it turns out that the logging of the array value was correct at the time that it was executed.  Once the post request returned, then the array was expanded.  I then looked at the 'logged' array and it was larger than the logged array length.  It was an issue with my javascript debugger (chrome).  Had I set a breakpoint instead, I would have stopped code execution and the array would have been the same size.  Thank you so much for responding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to log the length inside the callback. The callback you're writing inside the post function launches whenever the response is received, but you're trying to log the length before the response (so the callback is not called yet) and the array is not properly set.

Maybe read this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).